# How can I find the largest number from the given string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have two string i.e. `'This is a test as146634546576 string 12312523'` and `'This is a test as576 string 12344612523'`

Now I want to print the largest numbers i.e. `146634546576` and `12344612523` respectively. I have written the following code but it's printing only `146634546576` and `576`. Where it should be `12344612523` instead of `576`!

```
def findLargestNumber(text):
    front = -1
    li = []
    li1 = []

    for i in range(len(text)):
        if front == -1:
            if text[i].isdigit():
                front = i
            else:
               continue
        else:
            if text[i].isdigit():
               continue
            else:
                li.append(int(text[front:i+1]))
                front = -1
    return max(li)
    #print max(li)

    for w in text.split():
        li1.append(int(w))
    return max(li1)
    #print max(li1)

    if max(li)>max(li1):
        return max(li)
    else:
        return max(li1)

print findLargestNumber('This is a test as146634546576 string 12312523')
print findLargestNumber('This is a test as576 string 12344612523')
```

Comment: The code doesn't handle the case when the longest number is at the very end of the string. That number never gets appended to `li`.

Comment: `max(map(int, re.findall(r'(\d+)', s)))` would do the job!

Comment: Please do not vandalise your post. This may result in a [question ban](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `max()` with `re.findall`:

```
import re

a = 'This is a test as576 string 12344612523'

print(max(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', a))))
# 12344612523
```

Comment: Use finditer for a memory efficient approach

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
a = 'This is a test as146634546576 string 12312523'
b = 'This is a test as576 string 12344612523'
num_in_a = re.findall(r'[\d]+', a)
num_in_b = re.findall(r'[\d]+', b)
print(max(map(int, num_in_a)))
print(max(map(int, num_in_b)))
```

Output:

```
146634546576
12344612523
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

pa = re.compile(r'(\d+)')

def findLargestNumber(text):
  ma = pa.findall(text)
  num = [int(x) for x in ma]
  print(max(num))

findLargestNumber('This is a test as576 string 12344612523')
findLargestNumber('This is a test as146634546576 string 12312523')
```